# How to contact technical support for MS Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have found no way to contact any actual human beings for technical support regarding MS Graph service.

The graph support page doesn't contain any link to technical support: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support

Documentation issues are not either monitored by technical teams or the documentation issues are only meant to discuss the issues of the documentation (not in the actual service).

How to get support for technical issue such as:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3938

Browsing the documentation issues it seems the docs issues is full of technical issues that are not addressed by anyone in any reasonable time. The developer experience is not great if the service is not working as documented and there is no way to contact support.

Comment: And yes, the stackoverflow is wrong place for this kind of question but I hope actual graph team members might visit this place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise a support ticket in portal.azure.com. Please click help+support, then select New Support Request and select Technical, and then Azure Active Directory App Integration and Development and Problem type as GraphAPI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can open a support request in the [Azure portal](https://aad.portal.azure.com) by clicking the **Help** icon in the top nav (represented by a `?`)

[image: The help menu in Azure portal]

Alternatively if you have an Office 365 subscription you can contact support via the [Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com) by clicking the same icon and choosing the **Contact support** option.

[image: The help menu in Microsoft 365 admin center]

Looking at the GitHub issue you linked, I'm not sure that support could help you here. The documentation does not list `User.Read` as an applicable permission scope for the `getMemberObjects` API.

Comment: Hmm not so clear cut I see, the Markdown source for the docs does list `User.Read`, but the doc site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) does not. Pinged the API owner for clarification.

Comment: Please see my comment on the github issue.

Comment: And for contacting the support I have checked the Azure Portal but was unable to find MS Graph as one of the listed services to get support for (since it isn't Azure branded service?). So its unclear what type of ticket should be opened get in touch with the right people.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I didn't pay close attention when they showed me how this works :). It's issue type "Technical", service "Azure Active Directory App Integration and Development", Problem Type "GraphAPI", then choose an appropriate Problem Subtype, in this case "Microsoft Graph - developing for Azure AD". Not the most intuitive I know.